# ServiceStack.Redis Timeout with PooledRedisClientManager.IdleTimeOutSecs

Tags: redis, servicestack

connect over config time still connected.

default IdleTimeOutSecs is 240(sec)
ref: https://docs.servicestack.net/redis/client-managers

but i see redis command: client list
a lot of idle time over 240
still not disconnect

is this option no use?
how can i disconnect idle over time connect